# In Mercurial, make some files same on all branches

Tags: mercurial

This might be impossible or silly or bad practice or a good idea.

I have a branch with deployment scripts in my repo and whenever I update them (often) I need to merge this branch to all other current feature branches to get these scripts in an updated version. Is it possible to make some files the same no matter what branch I'm on?

I have considered subrepositories but they're discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> considered subrepositories but they're discouraged

It's just some developers opinion, nothing more (and GuestRepo will be better choice on this path) - splitting into separate repo is the most natural way (and my 1-st idea)

But if you'll prefer tricky way, you can

- Change scripts in one (or more) changesets, not mixed with other files
- Graft (`hg help graft`) only these changesets into all other branches, using `-t "internal:other"` additional option: in this case changes from source changesets will win automatically in conflicts and will appear in target. Your headache will be "one mandatory graft per branch"